# Unexpected behavior in material ui popover

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a lot of popvers in my page (every line in a table).
All of them work fine, the condition to opening the popover is By the id of the item.
But when i open the popover of the last item it jumps for a moment in the top-right side of the screen and then it goes to the right place.  (i can sort the table by name, id etc but that problem is always happening  to the last item)
When i print the anchorEl it always prints the right div.

Comment: I had to wrap my content in a `<Menu>` element to prevent this behavior. Not sure if it will work for the content in your popover. If you check, and it works, I can write a full answer with example.

Comment: @ErlendV it works! Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The material ui popover works as expected if you wrap the content in a Menu component:

```
<Popover>
    <Menu>
        <p>Content in popover here</p>
    </Menu>
</Popover>
```